# Time spent on the game server

Tags: php, date, time, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the total time spent on the server by a Player.

**I have a PHP cron job every 5 minutes that will query the details from the server**  https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

```
array (
  'id' => '1',
  'name' => 'Player',
  'score' => '3',
  'time' => '1234',
),
array (
  'id' => '2',
  'name' => 'Player 2',
  'score' => '12',
  'time' => '2453',
) + other 100k players.
// The 'time' is starting from 0 seconds when the player join the server, if she leave and then join again the time is starting from 0 seconds
```

Just adding the live data to DB from the PHP Query

```
| id | name     | last_score | total_score | last_time | total_time |
| -- | -------- | ---------- | ----------- | --------- | ---------- |
| 1  | Player   | 3          | 0           | 1234      | 0          |
| 2  | Player 2 | 12         | 0           | 2453      | 0          |
```

I'm not the owner of the servers where the players are online so i can't instantly LOG when the player leaves.

I'm trying to do something like this https://www.gametracker.com/server_info/109.120.135.78:2302/top_players/

Comment: Create a new table to store start and stop times by player ID, then your CRON job simply has to calculate the total from that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i have added an example more detalied now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
  $time = $query['Time'];
  $last = $db_players['last_time'];
  $total = $db_players['total_time'];

  if ($time < $last) {
    $total += $time;
  } else {
    $total += ($time - $last);
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).